# react-native page not rendering, but no errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, conditional-statements, rendering, jsx

This is the page code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Picker, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'; 

export default class SelectHours extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let tpd = this.props.navigation.getParam('tpd', 'two');

    switch(tpd) {
    case '1':
      tpd = 'one';
      break;
    case '2':
      tpd = 'two';
      break;
    case '3':
      tpd = 'three';
      break;
    case '4':
      tpd = 'four';
      break;
    default:
      alert(tpd);
    }

    return (
      <View styles={styles.container}>
        {tpd != 'one' ? true : false &&
          <View styles={styles.choices}>  
            <Text>Please select a time for each period of the day:</Text>
            <View styles={styles.choice}>
              <Text>Morning:</Text>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.morning}
                style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({morning: itemValue})}>
                <Picker.Item label='1' value={1}/>
                <Picker.Item label='2' value={2}/>
                <Picker.Item label='3' value={3}/>
                <Picker.Item label='4' value={4}/>
                <Picker.Item label='5' value={5}/>
                <Picker.Item label='6' value={6}/>
                <Picker.Item label='7' value={7}/>
                <Picker.Item label='8' value={8}/>
                <Picker.Item label='9' value={9}/>
                {tpd === 'two' ? true : false &&
                  <View>
                    <Picker.Item label='10' value={10}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='11' value={11}/>
                  </View>
                }
              </Picker>
              <Text>AM</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              {tpd === 'four' ? true : false &&
                <View styles={styles.choice}>
                  <Text>Late morning:</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.late_morning}
                    style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({late_morning: itemValue})}>
                    <Picker.Item label='10' value={10}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='11' value={11}/>
                  </Picker>
                  <Text>AM</Text>
                </View>
              }
            </View>
            <View>
              {tpd != 'two' ? true : false &&
                <View styles={styles.choice}>
                  <Text>Afternoon</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.afternoon}
                    style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({afternoon: itemValue})}>
                    <Picker.Item label='12' value={12}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='1' value={13}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='2' value={14}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='3' value={15}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='4' value={16}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='5' value={17}/>
                  </Picker>
                  <Text>PM</Text>
                </View>
              }
              <View styles={styles.choice}>
                <Text>Nighttime</Text>
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={this.state.nighttime}
                  style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({nighttime: itemValue})}>
                  {tpd === 'two' ? true : false &&
                    <View>
                      <Picker.Item label='12' value={12}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='1' value={13}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='2' value={14}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='3' value={15}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='4' value={16}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='5' value={17}/>
                    </View>
                  }
                  <Picker.Item label='6' value={18}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='7' value={19}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='8' value={20}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='9' value={21}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='10' value={22}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='11' value={23}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='12' value={24}/>
                </Picker>
                <Text>PM</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        }
        <View style={styles.choices}>
          {tpd == 'one' || tpd == 'one/shortcut' ? true : false &&
            <View>
              {tpd == 'one/shortcut' ? true : false &&
                <Text>What time would you like to start taking your medication every day?</Text> 
              } 
              <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.once}
                style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({once: itemValue})}>
                <Picker.Item label='1 AM' value={1}/>
                <Picker.Item label='2 AM' value={2}/>
                <Picker.Item label='3 AM' value={3}/>
                <Picker.Item label='4 AM' value={4}/>
                <Picker.Item label='5 AM' value={5}/>
                <Picker.Item label='6 AM' value={6}/>
                <Picker.Item label='7 AM' value={7}/>
                <Picker.Item label='8 AM' value={8}/>
                <Picker.Item label='9 AM' value={9}/>
                <Picker.Item label='10 AM' value={10}/>
                <Picker.Item label='11 AM' value={11}/>
                <Picker.Item label='12 PM' value={12}/>
                <Picker.Item label='1 PM' value={13}/>
                <Picker.Item label='2 PM' value={14}/>
                <Picker.Item label='3 PM' value={15}/>
                <Picker.Item label='4 PM' value={16}/>
                <Picker.Item label='5 PM' value={17}/>
                <Picker.Item label='6 PM' value={18}/>
                <Picker.Item label='7 PM' value={19}/>
                <Picker.Item label='8 PM' value={20}/>
                <Picker.Item label='9 PM' value={21}/>
                <Picker.Item label='10 PM' value={22}/>
                <Picker.Item label='11 PM' value={23}/>
                <Picker.Item label='12 PM' value={24}/>
              </Picker>
            </View>
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      morning: 5,
      late_morning: 10,
      afternoon: 14,
      nighttime: 8,
      once: 12
    }
  }

  methodSelect = () => {

  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  choices: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  choice: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});
```

Why is it not rendering any of the elements? The page comes up blank, just showing the `header` and `back` button. I have `alert`ed the variable (as you can see above), and it is showing the correct values, and should agree with at least one of the conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

`tbd != 'one' &&` not `tbd != 'one' ? ...` - the latter is redundant code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21441041)

Comment: this answer definitely solved my problem, and while I do not know why, it would be helpful to someone else having the same problem...

Comment: @ewizard, in the future when you get a blank screen and when you are developing with react, always have chrome console open and paste the error you are getting in the console and/or the error you are getting in terminal, either one should have given you an error. As it stands this post will not benefit future users as it is unclear what happened nor how you solved it.